# data-bind text not working

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, foreach

This is the part of the code which uses ko observableArray bindings. This code does not work.

```
<!-- ko foreach: environmentsList -->
<div data-bind="id: id">
<span data-bind="text: name">
</span>
<h3 data-bind="text: desc"></h3>
</div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

However this part works fine within my project. I feel both are the same. Is there any difference

```
<div id="2">
<span>Tab2</span>
<h3>desc2</h3>
</div>
```

I have a observable array in the view model

```
 environmentsList: { 
    func: ko.observableArray 
    }
```

It refers to the following JSON data

```
{ "environments": [
 { "id": "dev", 
   "name": "Development", 
   "desc": "Development Environment Content" 
 }, 
 { "id": "test", 
   "name": "Testing", 
   "desc": "Testing Environment Content" 
 }, 
 { "id": "prod", 
   "name": "Production", 
   "desc": "Production Environment Content" 
 }]}
```

Comment: Can you post your view model ?

Comment: @Damien
I have a observable array 
    `environmentsList: {
                func: ko.observableArray
            }`

It refers to the following JSON data
`{
    "environments": [
        {
            "id": "dev",
            "name": "Development",
            "desc": "Development Environment Content"
        },
        {
            "id": "test",
            "name": "Testing",
            "desc": "Testing Environment Content"
        },
        {
            "id": "prod",
            "name": "Production",
            "desc": "Production Environment Content"
        }
    ]
}`

Comment: Put it in the question...

Comment: Do you have a custon id binding `data-bind="id: id"`? Because KO does not a have a built in `id` binding...

Comment: I tried 

`<div data-bind="attr: {id: id}">`

But that doesn't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rename `environmentsList` to `environments` ...

http://jsfiddle.net/3WE23/